# assigning random values to a matrix with reference operator(&)

Tags: c++, c

Hi here is my problem i am able to input values for my matrix as such

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
```

how ever this is very tedious for matrices of a large order and i cant get the matrix to work with pointers and the rand function

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
&a[i][j] = -1 + rand() * (double)(2) / RAND_MAX;
```

this code compiles but results in errors also this with out the & operator compiles and gives me incorrect results as well

```
a[i][j] = -1 + rand() * (double)(2) / RAND_MAX;
```

what am i missing for the pointers to work as such?

Comment: what is `a`? don't you think it's relevant?

Comment: a[i][j] = -1 + rand() * (double)(2) / RAND_MAX; is syntactically correct, but you haven't posted the entire piece of code that includes both loops. Plus, as yi_H says, you haven't shown us the definition of a. Please post that.

Comment: I'm surprised this `&a[i][j] = -1 + rand() * (double)(2) / RAND_MAX;` did not cause a crash - you are attempting to assign a value to the pointer not the pointee. The second form is the correct way to assign the value - define *incorrect*, without that we cannot answer.

Comment: when you say "incorrect results" am I to assume you mean the range of the random number is wrong?  A statement about the incorrect results requires the correct results expected.

Comment: You can do `2.0` instead of `(double)(2)` and move the `-1` to the end of the expression to avoid adding a negative.

Comment: a[i][j] is a 100x100 matrix , and i get incorrect results meaning the determinant is always 0 and that makes me unable to compute the inverse of it as well as other things

Comment: your problem is not this code (don't use the &).  If I had to be psychic I would say you are might be putting your resulting determinant in an int which would round it down to 0 (or a is an int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `a` is an array of `int` (you are using `"%d"` to input values with `scanf`).

The expression you use generates `doubles` (ranging from `-1` to `1`) that when converted to `int` result in `0`. I guess that's what you see in `a`.

Make `a` an array of `double`s.

Comment: thanks , would there be an easy way to get the random function to work in this situation? i need random floating point numbers, my code is about 300 lines and changing around the function inputs from int to double gave me about 40 different errors

Comment: When you were using `scanf` what kind of numbers did you put into the array? If you need floating point values, you need to change the type of the array: it's as simple as that. If you can "pretend" `int`s are `double`s, try generating **integer** random numbers between -1,000,000 and 1,000,000 and divide by `1000000.0` before use in expressions requiring floating point.